# How to define a controller function that works for instances of any model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-resources, nested-routes

Implementing versioning for a Rails app I'd like to have a view that displays all versions of a model with some extra functionality like reverting etc.
I use the `paper_trail` gem for the versioning.

I know that I could do that by writing a controller function like `versions` and a view for every model but I'd like to do it for all models at once. This should be possible because the `model.versions` attribute is always structured identically.

Ideally the URL should look like `/pages/testpage/versions` while `testpage` is the page id.

This seems similar to the concept of nested routes in rails.

```
resources :pages do                                                    
    resources :versions                                                  
end
```

The problems with nested routes however are:

- Needs extra configuration per model
- I cannot access the `testpage` object without knowing of which model it is an instance.
  I also wasn't able to find a way to determine the model since the only thing that is provided to my versions controller is the params hash.

I'm completely open to alternative solutions that might not follow my initial ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it in your `ApplicationController` and define it as a helper_method.

For example

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_time

  def current_time
    Time.now
  end
end
```

Now you can cal `current_time` everywhere in controllers or views.

Also you can write separate Module/Class and define there your helpers methods. Than you should include this file into your `ApplicationController` as well

**UPD** after theme is changed

I didn't think about your actual question. But I can say that your approach is nod the best here.

You should create new **resource** instead of creating new functionality which will hard to be tested. So create new resource (controller): versions and play around this controller.

For example how it can work:

```
/versions/pages/132
/versions/comments/1003
```

How to realize it:

```
match "/versions/:model/:id", :to => "versions#index"
```

In your controller:

```
class VersionsController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    @object = my_type.find(params[:id])
    @versions = @object.versions
  end

  private
  def my_type
    params[:model].constantize
  end
end
```

Of course you can change routes the way you want:

```
match "/:model/:id/versions", :to => "versions#show"
```

So now your pretty `/pages/testpage/versions` will work fine for you without any new strange logic.

**UPD 2**

Imagine you have got this route:

```
match "/:model/:id/versions", :to => "versions#index", :as => :versions
```

And this objects:

```
@page = Page.last
@hotel = Hotel.find(123)
@comment = @page.comments.first
```

How will we create links for versions:

```
<%= link_to "Versions of this page", versions_path(:model => @page.class.to_s, :id => @page.id) %>
<%= link_to "Versions of this hotel", versions_path(:model => @hotel.class.to_s, :id => @hotel.id) %>
<%= link_to "Versions of this comment", versions_path(:model => @comment.class.to_s, :id => @comment.id) %>
```

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand but this does not seem to solve my problem. I changed the question a little so hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: Yes. Now it is another question :)

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to review the question after being done with the description.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually what I'd do when it's not possible to have a route like /pages/213/versions. I already have the versions controller which should contain the functions and views to display the list of versions of a model.

Comment: Ok, but trust me - this is not good idea to do what you want to do.

Comment: If you say it is a bad idea, why?

Comment: and also I've shown you how to generate links like you want `match "/:model/:id/versions", :to => "versions#show"`

Comment: The main reason is actually that I can't clear understand your approach. It looks like you want to create shared controller actions for all resorces

Comment: Yes thats basically what I want to do. I noticed that this doesn't work for resources that have a different :path than the default one. However this would also cause trouble when using your first suggestion. I'm confused and curious how other people implemented versioning of multiple models.

Comment: `However this would also cause trouble when using your first suggestion` I am pretty sure it wont :)

Comment: `params[:model].constantize` only works when the route (= URL segment) matches the model name. With a line like `resources :news_articles, :path => :news` this cannot work, or is there other magic happening?

Comment: other. Because it doesn't need to use this model resource path. It sends model name to Versions controller. You are sending not a path, but model name. I'll add some examples now.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing a param such as 'type' and stuff the model name there. Then in your controller you can do:

```
class VersionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    model = params[:type].classify.constantize
    @obj = model.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

For your links, you can pass queries to the link_to helper

```
<%= link_to versions_path(@model, :type => @model.class) %>
```

Or something along those lines.